# Query regarding possibilities of editor's reply

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics, paper-submission, elsevier

I have submitted my paper in an Elsevier math journal. For almost one year the status of my submission is "under review". Recently I have communicated with the handling editor. The editor informed me that he has received referee report and sent his decision to the editorial board for final decision (it would take another few weeks). I am very confused because the editor has not asked me for any revision of my manuscript. I would like to know what could be the possible outcome of the above situation. Does this automatically imply that the paper has been rejected or there is any possibility of the paper of getting accepted?

Comment: I would find it strange if your paper gets accepted without a single revision, if the reviewers didn't even find a small typo or anything. You should consider the possibility of rejection and be happy if it doesn't get rejected. If, however, it gets accepted without asking for a revision, I would be really careful, especially after almost a year.

Comment: With regards to the journal workflow question that I have marked this a duplicate of: you are at the editorial decision stage, where the Associate Editor has made their decision and the decision is getting confirmed by the Editors in Chief (who at many journals review all AE decisions).  That decision could be reject, revise, or accept, and you should know fairly soon.